How to use a multi index dataframe in python
I have this dataframe, and a constraint as follows:
L_model.constraint_b1 = pyo.ConstraintList()
for i in range(len(initial_demand)):
    for k in range(Nb):
        for t in demand.index:
            for e in range(len(bl_inx)):
                if k == bl_inx.inx[e] - 1:
                    L_model.constraint_b1.add(dft[i, k, t] <= dftmax.iloc[t, k, i])

How can I rewrite the constraint expression to use a conditional statement to select the correct column 'i' and row 't' the from dftmax based on the value of k, so that when k equals 0, the constraint reads: dft[i, k, t] <= dftmax.iloc[i,0,t] where
i=0,1,2,3 and t=0 to 23
my previous code was:
L_model.constraint_b1 = pyo.ConstraintList()
for i in range(len(initial_demand)):
    for k in range(Nb):
        for t in demand.index:
            if k == 0:
                L_model.constraint_b1.add(dft[i, k, t] <= Q1.iloc[t][i])
            elif k == 1:
                L_model.constraint_b1.add(dft[i, k, t] <= Q2.iloc[t][i])
            if k == 2:
                L_model.constraint_b1.add(dft[i, k, t] <= Q3.iloc[t][i])

and it worked properly, now I want to use a multi-index dataframe(dftmax) instead of q1, q2, q3 which have only one index.
In other words, I'm encountering an issue when trying to access values in my DataFrame dftmax. Specifically, I'm getting a pandas.errors.IndexingError: Too many indexers error when trying to access dftmax.iloc[t, k, i]. I'm iterating over i from 0 to 4 and t from 0 to 23, and for each specific k, I'm trying to evaluate the inequality dft[i, k, t] <= dftmax.iloc[t, k, i]. However, this results in the aforementioned error. I've tried using dftmax.loc[(t,k), column_name], but this gives me a different error: KeyError: 0. This error occurs when trying to access the value at index (t,k) in the dftmax DataFrame.
This is my dataframe:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please read Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question and [edit] your question to include code and data as text, not images.

Does this answer your question? Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

I do not know what is your exact problem, is the code working but not providing correct results or if there is an error. But it seems to me that you are not using .iloc operator correctly for a MultiIndex dataframe, which should result in an error like this:
IndexingError: Too many indexers
If that indeed is the case, in order for your code to work you should either use .iloc in the following way:
dftmax.iloc[row, i]; where row is indicating row of the dataframe (when time=1 and k=1 row=5)
Otherwise you could use .loc operator in the following way:
dftmax.loc[(t,k), column_name]

P.S.: You should clarify what is the exact problem you encountering (like error or code not giving the result that you expect) to be able to get better answers

I'm encountering an issue when trying to access values in my DataFrame dftmax. Specifically, I'm getting a pandas.errors.IndexingError: Too many indexers error when trying to access dftmax.iloc[t, k, i]. I'm iterating over i from 0 to 4 and t from 0 to 23, and for each specific k, I'm trying to evaluate the inequality dft[i, k, t] <= dftmax.iloc[t, k, i]. However, this results in the aforementioned error.
I've tried using dftmax.loc[(t,k), column_name], but this gives me a different error: KeyError: 0. This error occurs when trying to access the value at index (t,k) in the dftmax DataFrame.

@Nasim that's what you should put in your question. You can edit and add that information.

You probably get KeyError because you use i in the place of column_name. Column name should be a string and actual name of the column. For example for i=0 column name should be ‘dft_m1’
